# Converting matlab.object to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matlab, dataframe

I have used this code to run a matlab script inside python, the script is the file'matlab_to_python.m' and it has 1 output: a matlab table called 'matlab_table'.

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()

mytable = eng.matlab_to_python()
```

when I run this, mytable's type is:

```
In [28]: mytable
Out[28]: <matlab.object at 0x1ebe007fb70>
```

I want to be able to see this table as a pandas dataframe in python, any idea on how it could be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it seems that transferring a table directly into Python from MATLAB isn't yet [supported](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/handle-data-returned-from-matlab-to-python.html), you might leverage char conversions to make up the difference.

For example, you might convert the table into json format (1xN char), which could then be turned into a DataFrame using the `pandas.DataFrame.read_json` function.

```py
import matlab.engine
import pandas as pd
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()

# keep the table in MATLAB
eng.workspace['mytable'] = eng.matlab_to_python()

# pass a string representation to Python
jsontable = eng.eval('jsonencode(mytable)')

# convert back into a table
mytable = pd.read(jsontable)
```

An alternate approach could be to write from matlab to a csv file, which you can then read into Python via `pandas.DataFrame.read_csv`